# how to get a list of all the folders in current directory

Tags: python

How to get a list of all the folders in current directory. I know that we can get list of files and folders with `os.walk()` but I do not want to do the extra work as it is just unnecessary in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(f)]
```

Comment: holy cow I think we tied ... ahh you beat me by 4 seconds :P\

Comment: From what I see, my first version was 16 seconds before yours, but my edited version was 2 seconds after yours. I guess if you see 4 seconds before, there's a bit of margin for error here. Anyway, I saved 4 seconds by typing `f` instead of `fname`, which is probably cheating. :)

Comment: Just for completeness you obviously need a `import os` before that.

Comment: @halloleo: Well, yes, but I assume the OP already knows how to import `os` if he knows how to use `os.walk`…

Answer (score 5):

```
print [fname for fname in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(fname)]
```

Answer (score 4):

The dirs in each directory are the second item in the tuple returned by os.walk, in each interation. So,one can simply do:

```
dirs = os.walk(".").next()[1]
```

No need to iterate over the remaining of os.walk.

Comment: but would the function not precompute both the list. I am new to python so bear with me if its just too basic.

Comment: i don't get it, why nobody is up-voting this piece of pure beauty! you could even do a `dirs, files = os.walk(".").next()[1:]` ah, so efficient! :-)

Comment: @DonQuestion: The only problem with this one is that the OP explicitly didn't want to use `os.walk`. There's a good argument that the only reason he didn't want it is that he didn't realize how easy this was, so I gave it a +1 myself, but I can see why others might not.

Comment: @DonQuestion I meant that since `os.walk()` is supposed to give you 2 lists so does this not function pre compute the list of `dirs` and `files` and we are just using list of `dirs`

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: Well, `listdir()` also computes everything and then throws some of it away. The way most filesystems work, there's really no way around that. If you're worried about efficiency, benchmark the two and compare. I suspect the `listdir` solution is faster in most cases, but I also suspect they're both fast enough that it rarely matters.

Comment: @abarnert ohh, I didn't know that `lsitdir` throws some of it away that is why I explicitly excluded the `os.walk()` option.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: Sorry for being confusing: `listdir` itself doesn't throw anything away (except for '.' and '..' on POSIX), but anything that filters it to skip over non-directories has to receive everything, and throw away the non-directories, which is most of what you're worried about `walk` doing.

Comment: timit with 10.000 iterations on my homedirectory took me 5.00s for jsbueno's version; 3.44s for abarnert's version and 3.34s for my version. You see performance just doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir

path = '.'
dirs = filter(isdir, listdir(path))
```

Comment: This solution is identical to the one @JonanBeasley and I already wrote, but rewritten to avoid list comprehensions. What's the point of that?

Comment: If you think comprehensions are ugly, you may be using the wrong language. Guido strongly disagrees, and he's the BDFL. (As the Zen says, TOOWTDI, "although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch".) He's been itching to eliminate `map`, `filter`, and friends with every release of the language since comprehensions were added—and, while people have so far restrained him from doing that, he _has_ blocked numerous patches that would make `map` and friends faster, more flexible, etc. while pushing to make list comprehensions (and generator expressions) faster and more powerful.

Comment: As for the Zen numbers, I'm pretty sure anyone who doesn't hate comprehensions would disagree with you on 1, 3 (0 higher-order functions is simpler than 1 higher-order function), and 7 (if you don't know how to read a simple comprehension, you don't know how to read Python). For 5, they're both equally flat (there are no nested comprehensions or anything). There's also 2: it's obvious what `isdir` is being called on in the comprehension, because you see the `isdir(f)`. tim-peters-quoting-ly yours.

Comment: The reason is that the same discussion happens every time, and always ends the same way. First people say "but map is cool, it's Lisp" and other people say "Yeah, but Haskell is cooler than Lisp, so you lose", and then someone says "But wait, there's too much legacy code, do we really want to break that all for no compelling reasons?", so Guido says, "OK, just this once, as long as everyone promises nicely not to teach new users to write more legacy code using map, we'll leave it in", and the discussion is settled for a year or two.

Comment: Maybe, but i'm not really interested in those petty discussions. I guess you are right and i'm wrong but in these rare cases where simple true/false validations may be applied i will choose filter over list-comprhension as long they may stay in the language! :-) TO hell with #13 then! ;-)

Comment: Well, it's not as if you have anything to worry about as long as you stay with 2.x; Guido is far more strongly against ever releasing a 2.8 than he is against any specifics in the language…